# svgjs with existing svg tag

Tags: javascript, svg.js

I'm trying to init svg.js with existing svg tag,
`var svg = SVG.get('mysvg');var draw = svg.doc(); draw.polyline()....`
but I get this error: the doc is undefined for svg. how could I get the doc so that I could draw line?

Answer (score 0):

When `mysvg` is the id of the root svg element you already got the doc with `SVG.get('mysvg')`. However calling `doc()` on the doc will also return the doc so your code should work fine.

So the 2 possibilities are:

1. there is no svg with the id `mysvg`
2. you are executing this code before the DOM is loaded
   --> where in your html document is your script tag located? It should be at the end of the body

When all these answers dont match, we need more code because the error is not in the code you posted.